# com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices

I am very new to the microservices and trying to run the code from link: https://dzone.com/articles/advanced-microservices-security-with-spring-and-oa . When I simply run the code I see the following error comes.

What is the issue ?

```
com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:111) ~[eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134) ~[eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137) ~[eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77) ~[eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134) ~[eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.getAndStoreFullRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:1030) [eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.fetchRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:944) [eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.refreshRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:1468) [eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient$CacheRefreshThread.run(DiscoveryClient.java:1435) [eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_144]

2017-09-09 18:53:11.909 ERROR 16268 --- [tbeatExecutor-0] c.n.d.s.t.d.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient  : Request execution error
```

I have not installed anything special on to the system. Please let me know what do I need to install?

[image]

Answer (score 109):

I find I have to add these two applications to the appllication.properties,it can work.Only one is not enough.

```
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false

eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
```

Comment: This helped me resolve my problem, thanks for this @xuezhongyu01

Comment: Thanks ... This is the correct answer ... ``eureka.client.fetch-registry=false`` included this line in my eureka microservice.

Comment: Yeah, but this essentially makes this client unable to be discoverable. Is that ideal? Maybe for this case... For me, it was essentially: 1) start the `@EnableEurekaServer` app first; 2) Start any `@EurekaDiscoveryClient` apps afterward. This is mostly just a timing issue (tries to connect, fails, tries again, fails, tries again, succeeds)

Comment: To clarify, the two properties above are used inside the eureka server, not the client.  This prevents the server from registering itself.

Comment: Thanks eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false resolved my issue.

Answer (score 24):

This is happening because it is trying to connect to any known server, so to stop that error, a known server is eureka server on port 8761 which is its default port, you will have to update the application.properties with following

```
server.port=8761
```

To avoid eureka from registering itself, you add this to the application.properties

```
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
```

Ensure that EurekaServer is enabled, for example using spring boot you write the below on the main class.

```
@EnableEurekaServer
```

Please pardon me providing solution using .properties file but that is what i work with but .yml configurations shouldn't be too different.

Answer (score 14):

You need to create Eureka Registry Server which is another microservice. It's main class incase of an SpringBoot application, should have @EnableEurekaServer annotation.

Then in your Eureka Client you will have to mention the  Registry server URL in appliation.yml as below :

```
spring:
  application:
    name: stock-service

server:
  port: 8083


eureka:
  client:
    registerWithEureka: true
    fetchRegistry: true
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8084/eureka/
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
```

where defaultzone should hold the value of your Eureka Registry.

Once you do all these configurations you need to Get the Eureka Registry microservice up and then you can get the Eureka client up. Once your Registry is up you will not face this exception.

Answer (score 11):

This particular message is just a warning. Your application is attempting to register with Eureka but Eureka is not responding. You can either start an instance of Eureka or disable the automatic registration by adding the following to your application.yml.

```
eureka:
  client:
    register-with-eureka: false
```

Comment: oh, I think I dont have Eureka installed on my windows box ? Is that the problem ? Do I need to installed that ?

Comment: You probably do not need it for what you are doing. Just disable it so you do not see a message every 5 seconds. If you would like to learn more about Eureka, start here (https://spring.io/guides/gs/service-registration-and-discovery/)

Answer (score 6):

I was facing the same error when my Eureka client i.e microservice trying to register herself with Eureka Server.

> **Client registration eureka service failure registration failed Cannot execute request on any known server**

This error message comes because of following two possibilities.

1) The defaultZone address is incorrect , either its misspelled or the space is missing after **:**.

2) Spring security implemented on Eureka server require a valid CSRF token be sent with every request. Eureka clients will not generally possess a valid cross site request forgery (CSRF) token. So you will need to disable this requirement for the /eureka/** endpoints.

After disabling the CSRF token with follwoing line of code my Eureka client successfully register them selves with Eureka Server.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().ignoringAntMatchers("/eureka/**");
        super.configure(http);
    }
}
```

Also below is the link from spring docs.

https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Greenwich.SR2/single/spring-cloud.html#_securing_the_eureka_server

Comment: Can you please tell us spring boot and spring cloud versions you have tried with? I have the same issue and the culprit is spring security.  I have tried your solution but no difference. I have already looked at docs and https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/2754. no difference. By the way my `spring-boot` version is: 2.5.2 and `spring-cloud` version is: 2020.0.3

Comment: @MortezaBandi my fixed solution was with spring-boot 2.2.6.RELEASE and spring-cloud Hoxton.SR3

Answer (score 5):

Version for dependencies:

- **Spring Boot**: `2.5.6`
- **Spring Cloud**: `2020.0.4`

### Eureka Server App

#### `application.yaml`

```yaml
server:
  port: 8010
eureka:
  client:
    fetch-registry: false
    register-with-eureka: false
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8010/eureka
```

#### `MyEurekaServerApplication.java`

```java
@EnableEurekaServer
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyEurekaServerApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyEurekaServerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

### Eureka Client App

#### `application.yaml`

```yaml
eureka:
  client:
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8010/eureka
```

If you use `default-zone` instead of `defaultZone`, then the **Eureka Client App** throws an exception when registering on the **Eureka Server**.

#### `MyEurekaClientApplication.java`

```java
@EnableEurekaClient
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyEurekaClientApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyEurekaClientApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I got the same error. In my case, in the `application.properties` file of my client application I misspelled the `defaultZone` word. I wrote `default-zone` but it must be `defaultZone`.

**Client App** `application.properties`:

```
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://localhost:8030/eureka/
```

Hostname and port may differ in your case.

Answer (score 2):

**If your eureka server is deployed/running without username and password use below properties.**

```
spring.application.name=Hello-World
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://eurekaserver:password@localhost:9100/eureka
server.port=9200
eureka.client.fetch-registry=true
```

**If your eureka server is deployed/running with username and password use below properties.**

```
spring.application.name=Hello-World
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://eurekaserverusername:eurekaserverpassword@localhost:9100/eureka
server.port=9200
eureka.client.fetch-registry=true
```

Answer (score 1):

Look for the filterType() in ZuulLoggingFiler.java. I had the same problem. Then i saw my filter was returning null. so I changed it to "post" and it worked.

```
@Override
public String filterType() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return "post";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your URL and port number of eureka server 
 provided in "eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone" property.

Answer (score 1):

Similar error will be thrown when you have misspelled anything in the value of defaultZone. For ex: someone has misspelled eureka to euraka. Double check it.

```
defaultZone : http://localhost:8761/eureka
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding the following lines in application.properties solved it:

`server.port=8761`

`eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false`

`eureka.client.fetch-registry=false`

The first one is optional.

The other two properties are used to tell Eureka Server that "Hey, you're the only Eureka Server in this context, don't try to find other Eureka Servers"

If we don't mention these, our Eureka Server will try to find and register itself on other Eureka Servers and will eventually throw the Transport Exception.

Answer (score 0):

for me its working after connecting to internet because it need to download some dependence first time.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this property in your microservice which you want to connect with the naming server:

```
eureka.instance.hostname=localhost
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's set aside the answers given above. Maybe you didn't get the server that has `@EnableEurekaServer`annotation program up. :)

Answer (score 0):

Stater config is needed sometimes, to pom.xml add

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

In application.properties add

```
spring.config.import=optional:configserver:http://localhost:8888
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue was in my build.gradle file.
I just removed this part from my build.gradle file:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

Then my gradle file changed to this:

```
buildscript {
    apply from:"../dependencies.gradle"
    ext {
        set('springBootVersion', "2.1.8.RELEASE")
        set('springCloudVersion',"Greenwich.SR2" )
        set('springCloudServicesVersion', "3.1.0.RELEASE")
        set('springBootAdminVersion','2.1.6')
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.1.4.RELEASE")
        classpath "io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:1.0.8.RELEASE"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use below property you can change ip based on yours
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone: ${eureka_url:http://localhost:8761/eureka}

Answer (score 0):

### I was getting same error when I ran service registry project.
Below step fixed my issue and able to run project.

Instead of using below:

```
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
```

Use This in application.properties:-

```
eureka.client.registerWithEureka=false
eureka.client.fetchRegistry=false
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: change the version]

1.change the version
2. add in yml file -

eureka:
instance:
hostname: localhost
client:
register-with-eureka: false
fetch-registry: false
server:
port: 8761

add @EnableEurekaServer at main class