# Netflix Eureka error : com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server

Tags: java, spring-boot, netflix-eureka

I am facing a situation where the Netflix Eureka discovery server keeps on showing the error `com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute the request on any known server` each time an application attempts to register. I have tried to compare the `pom` file with the one in the [spring tutorials](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-service-registration-and-discovery/tree/master/complete) but I find no difference. Here is a stacktrace of the error from Eureka:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.uri(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder;
at javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.fromUri(UriBuilder.java:120) ~[javax.ws.rs-api-2.1.jar:2.1]
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:911) ~[jersey-servlet-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:875) ~[jersey-servlet-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:829) ~[jersey-servlet-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:88) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
at org.springframework.web.filter.AbstractRequestLoggingFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractRequestLoggingFilter.java:262) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
```

And the print out from the microservice application :

```
com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:112)
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134)
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137)
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77)
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134)
at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.getAndStoreFullRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:1051)
at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.fetchRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:965)
at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.refreshRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:1479)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46131196/com-netflix-discovery-shared-transport-transportexception-cannot-execute-reques)

Comment: @AlexpandiyanChokkan you are correct, but I also tried out the answers in the mentioned question. Unfortunately;y, none of them solves my issue.

Comment: I have tried the following source https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-service-registration-and-discovery/tree/master/complete and it is working fine for me. Please try update the project and run it again.